# Can't find model database when roslaunch'd, but can find it when Gazebo is run by itself

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a robot model (wam), launch file, and world file. When I run Gazebo by itself, I see the robot model show up in the "insert" menu and I can drop it in without problem. However, when I try to roslaunch my launch file, I get  `Error [parser.cc:528] Unable to find uri[model://wam_description]` . Not only that, but all of a sudden I can no longer see the robot in the "insert" menu (I can't see any of my robots. Only the .gazebo folder and the online database).

Any advice on how to get this roslaunch working?

I'm using Gazebo 4 and am running ROS Indigo.

I have a catkin workspace in `~/path/ros_stuff`.

In `ros_stuff`, I have a number of gazebo model directories, but the relevant ones are:
`wam_gazebo` and `wam_description`.

Within `wam_gazebo` I have:

```
launch/
  wam.launch
worlds/
  wam.world
CMakeLists.txt
package.xml
```

Within `wam_description` I have:

```
meshes/
  ... a bunch of stl files.
CMakeLists.txt
package.xml
model.config
wam.sdf
```

in my .bashrc:

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/path/ros_stuff/src/
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/path/ros_stuff/devel/setup.bash
```

**Edit:**
I can succesfully `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch` but my model directory (ros_stuff) still doesn't show up in the "insert" menu.

**Bug confirmed. Workaround:**
Others have no confirmed this bug in the ticket that Jose posted.  As a workaround until it's fixed, one can copy their models to the ~/.gazebo folder and they'll show up even when roslaunch is used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7937/can%27t-find-model-database-when-roslaunch%27d,-but-can-find-it-when-gazebo-is-run-by-itself./) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-02-04**:
Does roslaunch preserve environment variables?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2015-02-05**:
See my comment on Nate's comment. It doesn't seem to actually change the value in the environment.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-02-05**:
Maybe the answers.ros.org folks would have some betting insight into this? Have you posted this there as well?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/425/william/) on 2015-02-11**:
Can you post the contents of your launch file, or at least the part of the launch file which launches gazebo?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2015-02-13**:
William, this happens even when I roslaunch the standard empty_world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was able to reproduce the issue. It is not present if you don't use the roslaunch command.

I've [created an issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issue/27/roslaunch-not-working-properly-when-using) to track it down and fix our current tutorial.

Thanks Ben for reporting.

**Update 25/03/2015:** this has been fixed and released for gazebo 4.1.2 and 5.1.0

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-02-16**:
There is a fix in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1430/preserve-previous-gazebo_model_path-values/diff